# Why doesn't WordPress install work on my XAMPP installation?

Tags: wordpress, installation, xampp

XAMPP is installed and I have Apache and MySQL working.  I have copied the WordPress files into a folder under htdocs. I have created a database for WordPress in MySQL.  I am running on Windows 11 Pro.

Any ideas why this is not working?

I can open the phpadmin webpage with no problems.  When I try to open the WordPress folder I get the error message:

```
404 Not Found.  
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 Server at localhost Port 9090
```

Comment: I would validate if the Apache config file is expecting your files in the same folder where you copied them. Second, I would try to replace your WordPress file with a sample index.html file to validate Apache.

Comment: @hschmid Can you add more details like screenshots of your WordPress directory as well the screen of browser.
Also check few things is create directory and run simple php program from that directory.
Make sure that you have installed version is correct for WordPress.

Comment: If I try to execute a php file in that directory in MS Edge it displays the code instead of executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  My stupid mistake.  I created two instances of XAMPP and I copied the WordPress files in the inactive folder.  I deleted the inactive XAMPP and copied the WordPress files into the active htdocs folder and now everything works.

Next time you hear of this problem ask them to make sure they don't have two instances of XAMPP installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that your folder under htdocs has the WP files extracted into it and that its not in a further subfolder. so it should be 'htdocs/wpsite/' and in wpsite you should see the wp-config.php file, among others. if you don't see the wp-config.php in the root of that folder, look for it, note the location then got to localhost/wpsite/actualfolder and see if it loads. If it still doesn't load make sure that xampp is running and that all the relevant options are enabled, apache etc. If it still refuses then check that your wp-config file is setup correctly with the appropriate database name, user, and password.

Comment: The installation script does not run so the wp-config.php is still named wp-config-sample.php.  The files are in the correct folder.  It seems as though it can't run php in this subfolder.  It does run the php in other folders. (the Welcome to XAMPP and phpMyAdmin page) Is there a reason that it does not run php files in the Wordpress subfolder under htdocs?

Comment: @fhschmid I would rename your wp-config-sample to wp-config then fill in the database, user and password areas and then try again. If it continues to fail, try using Local by flywheel, its the simplest way to do local wordpress dev. https://localwp.com/

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think you have renamed the file while extracting (from zip file) and because of that the server is unable to identify it. So delete the extracted WordPress file and then re-extract it without changing the name. After that follow the regular procedure to paste it in htdocs file. It will work!

Comment: I pasted the extracted folder into the htdocs folder and the site still does not work.  I get the same error message (Error 404)